# Npm run dev excessive memory and cpu usage - Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-livewire

I'm stuck with a job, with Laravel 10 I implemented livewire datatables, laravel excel, I made a form with livewire, suddenly my memory and cpu began to increase by 80/90% to the point of almost not being able to use the PC and much less the site in the browser. The project was completely fluid and from one moment to the next the microprocessor and memory began to increase abruptly. Running tests commenting code that had added nothing changed. The last test I did was run just php artisan serve and it works much better, but not perfect. When I run npm run dev there it fires up the resources without even opening the browser. Install debugbar and I don't see anything weird.

I use windows 11 with i5 and 16gb ram.

First I was using docker with WSL2 and I thought that was the problem, so I installed XAMPP and to my surprise the same thing happens.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build"
},
```

taskmgr:
[image]

terminal:
[image]

debugbar:
[image]

Can you point me to some guidance, some test that I can perform. Tell me any information you require, I ask for a little help please. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have similar problem. After npm run dev (which run vite dev) my CPU and RAM goes crazy and sometime kill other processes on VPS (out of memory happend). This is about 20 seconds, after that, everything return to OK.  I use Laravel 10, vite v5, had Linux VPS 4GB ram and 8cores CPU. Any idea how to debug this please?